# Custom TextField in Flutter: add superscript

Tags: flutter

Is it possible in flutter to develop custom TextField  to input numbers with superscript like  10<sup>2</sup>  ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there has to be a way for the user to specify that he is getting into (and out of) superscript mode (say using a specific key). Using a TextInputFormatter to 'trap' these locations - there should be a way to then display the text the way you wanted.

Alternatively, as in stackoverflow where we use ``` to highlight code and there is a display-only section that shows how the text looks, you can do all sorts of text display for formatting the text as per the codes in the typed text without needing to use the TextInputFormatter method.